# Puzzled by this JavaScript code snippet

Tags: javascript

For this snippet, I'm not surprised global variable 'a' evaluates to be 5.

http://jsfiddle.net/MeiJsVa23/gZSxY/ :

```
var a = 10;

function func(){
  a = 5;
}

func();   // expect global variable 'a' to be modified to 5;

alert(a); // and this prints out 5 as expected. No surprise here.
​
```

But how come for this code snippet, global variable 'a' evaluates to be 10 and not 5? It's as if the `a = 5` never happened.

http://jsfiddle.net/MeiJsVa23/2WZ7w/ :

```
var a = 10;

function func(){
  a = 5;
  var a = 23;
}

func();   // expect global variable 'a' to be modified to 5;

alert(a); // but this prints out 10!! why?
```

​

Comment: Wow, I think your question has been answered ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to variable hoisting: anything defined with the `var` keyword gets 'hoisted' to the top of the current scope, creating a local variable `a`. See: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting

Answer (score 2):

So, there are two things are going here: [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) and [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Because the first one, variable declarations are "hoisted" to the top, so your code is equivalent to:

```
var a = 10;

function func(){
    var a;
    a = 5;
    a = 23;
}
```

And because the second one, you're "shadowed" the global variable `a` with a local ones, so the changes are not reflected to the global `a`.

Comment: +1 for the example and bothering to explain what hoisting means.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "[variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)".  `var` declarations (and `function()` declarations) are moved to the top of their scope.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with **hoisting**.

In the function, a local variable with the same name is declared. Even though it happens after your modification, it is deemed to have been declared before it - this is called hoisting.

Local variables hoist for declaration but not value. So:

```
function someFunc() {
    alert(localVar); //undefined
    var localVar = 5;
}
```

Functions, if declared with `function name() {...` syntax, hoist for both declaration and value.

```
function someFunc() {
    alert(someInnerFunc()); //5
    function someInnerFunc() { return 5; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 10;  //a is 10

function func(){
  a = 5; //a is 5
  var a = 23; // a is now in local scope (via hoisting) and is 23
}

func();   

alert(a); // prints global a = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the statement `var a = 23` creates a local variable *for the whole scope*. So the global `a` is shadowed for the entirety of `func()`, not just for the lines below the statement. So in your second snippet, `a = 5` is assigning to the local variable declared below.