# Why is it that Javascript variables are created undefined even if they don't pass if statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Take this for example.

```
if (b) b = 1;
```

Reference Error. b is not defined. Makes sense but if I do this...

```
if (b) var b = 1;
```

I get undefined in console. and now when I look up what b is it shows as undefined.

If I try to do the same if statement again, it doesn't pass because b is neither true or false, it is undefined, but I guess my question is why does it show up as undefined? Does Javascript go through the if statement regardless if the if statement passes or fails? Thanks.

Comment: `var` gets hoisted so `b` gets initialised as `undefined` at the beginning of the scope. Think of it like `var b; if (b) b = 1;`.

Comment: What Paul said, vars gets hoisted, and the obvious thing to do would be to declare your variables **before** you check if they are thruthy/falsy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Puzzled by this JavaScript code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397151/puzzled-by-this-javascript-code-snippet) (if you understand this question/answer, then you'll understand why it works as such)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427311/local-variable-impact-global-variable-javascript-variable-scoping - another example of `var` in a conditional.

Comment: One clue: `b = undefined; if (b) ` will find b to be false because a bunch of values are false in javascript, including `null` and `undefined` and `0` and the empty string and others.

Comment: @PaulS. if you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. I guess I was looking for the term variable hoisting.

Comment: And thank you @pst I wish I saw those questions but couldn't find them! Also just wondering if variable hoisting is language-agnostic or is it something special in only Javascript?

Comment: @aug This is very *language-specific* just as with the general Scoping rules. (JavaScript scope is somewhat similar to Python, but in Python one must declare globals, not locals; JavaScript scope is somewhat similar to Ruby, but Ruby requires a variable to appear as an lvalue before use and does not chain to a "global" scope; JavaScript scope is not very similar to C/Java in which each block introduces a new scope and variables must be declared ahead, etc ..)

Comment: ahh thank you :) @pst if you want to post an answer I can accept that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `var`s gets hoisted to the beginning of the scope they are in, initialising their values to `undefined`. The value is then set when execution reaches the line the `var` was in originally.

In your second example, `b` gets initialised as `undefined` before the `if` is encountered, due to the `var`. Think of it as the same as writing the following

```
var b;
if (b) b = 1;
```

After this code is executed, `b` will still be `undefined` because it will never run into the `if` block as the initial value is *falsy*.

As mentioned by [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst), this is a language specific *feature* of JavaScript, so don't expect the same behaviour when writing code in other languages.

Comment: Do you have any official resource calling this behaviour "hoisting"? Like anywhere in the ECMAScript-Spec?

Comment: @dave I was able to look it up and yes there is a term for hoisting. Crazy right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Answer (score 0):

JS is not going thru the if statement, but rather it's reading the `if` part of the statement, and since `b` is not defined anywhere but within the `if` statement, you get `undefined`.

Comment: This doesn't address the behavior of `var`.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't explain how putting `var` in front of a variable changes how global-ized (hoisted?), but I think that the OP was asking if JS goes thru the `if` statement, which I don't think it does if the `if` is false, no?